# Why local area connection not appear in Network and Sharing Center?

Tags: networking, ethernet, windows-server-2016

I install windows server 2016 on MSI allinone .
I can connect to internet by wifi but when connect cable from modem to allinone, dont detect it!

I check `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` path in os and found that local area connection not appear.

I check `Device manager` . I have two unknows devices

[image]
[image]
How can i fix this?

Comment: You need to install the drivers for your Ethernet controller. Download the required driver from the manufacture of your device.

Comment: I try this but get error that : can not install driver . No Intel(R) adapters are present in this computer

Comment: You need to install the motherboard drivers. Windows doesn't always supply the chipset drivers you would need, such as the USB host controller drivers, which would prevent your network adapter from working. Then you might also need to install the driver that comes with the network adapter.

Comment: What makes you think your ethernet adapter is manufactured by Intel?  Only your wireless adapter is an Intel device.  Check your OEM website for the type of ethernet device you have, or identify it in your question, by editing it (but the reason it does not work is you have no drivers for it installed).